# Error while downloading files from IBM serverless function

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I have some files in IBM cloud object storage bucket. I need to download those files  to my local storage using a serverless function.
I tried it using Python but encountering a problem. 
And I also wanted to ask where to provide the path of local storage folder.

It will be a great help if some code will be added.
Thank you.

**I tried this :**

```
import ibm_boto3

from ibm_botocore.client import Config

import os,os.path

import pathlib

import glob


import requests


    cos = ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3',

    ibm_api_key_id='my-api-key',

    ibm_service_instance_id='id-from-service-credential',

    config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),

    endpoint_url='https://s3.eu-gb.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud')


try:

res = cos.download_file(Key='abc.txt',Bucket='cloud-college-bucket0',Filename='abc.txt')


except Exception as e:

    print(Exception, e)

else:

    print('File Downloaded')
```

**Error encountered is :**

"error": "File Downloaded\n/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_botocore/vendored/requests/api.py:67: DeprecationWarning: You are using the post() function from 'ibm_botocore.vendored.requests'.  This is not a public API in ibm_botocore and will be removed in the future. Additionally, this version of requests is out of date.  We recommend you install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.post() function instead.\n  DeprecationWarning\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/action/1/src/exec__.py\", line 43, in \n    from main__ import main as main\nImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'main__' (/action/1/src/main__.py)\n"
}

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no direct way to achieve this usecase. You can check the pointers below to fix the code above

For the error, you can check the supported packages list with Python runtime [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-runtimes#python-packages) before using them in your action.

If you have a package that is not in the list, you can always [package Python code with a virtual environment in .zip files](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-prep#prep_python) or [Packaging code in Docker images](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-prep#prep_docker_pkg)

You may have to use the [S3 API to download the object](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cos/cos-compatibility#download-an-object)

Comment: HI @Vidyasager I am using ibmcloudsql lib and I am testing my application in virtual env, looks good and giving expected results. But when I am invoking an action after pushing .zip file via CLI it gives an error : "error": "The action did not initialize and exited unexpectedly."